# How to use a property set in a dialog

Tags: installshield, installscript

I'm using InstallShield Professional 2016. I have an SQLLogin dialog, which creates a property IS_SQLSERVER_DATABASE for the server name, and I'll need to use this property in an InstallScript script to create the final connection string.

How can I get the value of IS_SQLSERVER_DATABASE in the script to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, SQLLogin dialog will set the IS_SQLSERVER_DATABASE property and if you write with InstallScript, just use this property directly ...

```
function STRING getConnectionString()
  STRING strConnection;
begin
  strConnection = IS_SQLSERVER_DATABASE ^ " your connection parameters";
  return strConnection;
end;
```

And if you write with, for example, VBScript ...

```
szSqlDB = Session.Property("IS_SQLSERVER_DATABASE")
```